# for few days I have had a problem with Firefox and Amazon USA account

Tags: firefox

Ubuntu-dde 20.04 version. Not sure version number of Firefox.
What is weird is, it works fine if I go to UK website.
USA website gives me error message if I log in.. but if I clear cookies, etc, so it thinks I am  a new customer, it goes from email to item just fine, or goes from search to item just fine, displaying info about products.
Website seems to work fine on phone and on Amazon Fire.
Amazon claims not a problem on their end.
So, has a firefox update created a cookie or login handling problem?
Or is my old dell computer creating problems?
Only been happening since last week..
Thanks guys. I know someone has a better answer than tech support at amazon tht wants e to cler history and cookies and passwords or download their app..

Comment: "_USA website gives me error message if I log in_" ... what message?

Comment: We're sorry.An error occured.  We are working to resolve ptible.